# Showing multiple components in one page Angular 8 by calling the selector attribute

Tags: angular, angular-components

I want to show two components on one page. In order to do that I defined the two components **EmployeeDetails** and **EmployeeList**. I want to show the details on the right side and the list on the left. I'm trying to do this with the *selector* but it doesn't work for the EmployeeDetails. When I change the constructor of the employeeDetails to `constructor(private employeeService: EmployeeService){}` it works otherwise not. What do I have to change if I want the constructor to stay the same?

EployeeDetails-Component:

```
@Component({  
  selector: 'app-employee-detail',
  templateUrl: './employee-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee-detail.component.scss']
            })
export class EmployeeDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private employeeService: EmployeeService, private router: Router, private employerService: 
              EmployerService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  ...
  }
```

EmployeeList-Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee-list',
  templateUrl: './employee-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee-list.component.scss']
})
export class EmployeeListComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private employeeService:EmployeeService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Employee-Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee',
  templateUrl: './employee.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee.component.scss']
})
export class EmployeeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private employeeService: EmployeeService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

My Employee HTML-looks like this:

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h2 class="jumbotron bg-secondary text-white">Employee Register</h2>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <app-employee-list></app-employee-list>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <app-employee-detail></app-employee-detail>
  </div>
</div>
```

EmployeeDetails HTML: (just for testing)

```
<p>employee-details works!</p>
```

EmployeeList HTML: (just for testing)

```
<p>employee-list works!</p>
```

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "it doesn't work for the EmployeeDetails". What is the result you get, is there a error, etc.

Comment: Fast thing I spot is that EmployeeService is duplicated in the constructor

Comment: I don't get any error, but the paragraph <p>employee-details works</p> isn't shown if I load the page.

Comment: Once it is EmployeeService and the other time it's Employe**r**Service in the constructor, so that shouldn't be the problem.